# How to use colum name as a value and filter highest value MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

This is my [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebfcfe) I have managed to get all values i need except i havent figured out how to check which value from table "tickets" has highest value as column name in table "draws" and then assign value from table "coefficients".

So, if table tickets have values: 9,12,1,11,14,10
And table "draws" have values: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,1,35
Highest value column name from this "ticket" in table draws is 4th value in table tickets (number 1) and because that is 34th value in table draws i should get 34th value from table "coefficients"

Some PHP or even vb.net function would be ok because i need this for a simple application and it does not matter how it's done as long as it is correct.

Oh, yes... i forgot to put my sql here:

```
SELECT *,
c.coefficient
FROM tickets t
INNER JOIN draws d ON
(FIELD(t.b1,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b2,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b3,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b4,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b5,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b6,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
INNER JOIN coefficients c
ON c.number = FIELD(t.b6,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)
WHERE draw='1' AND status = '1'
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: How are `tickets` and `coefficients` related?

Comment: I could not understand the schema either. And looks like you need to have a simple join and count(*)

Comment: If this is what you want, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42057/1.

Comment: No, not really... The problem is I can't figure out how to use column name as a value. Because if i can find which number from table "tickets" have highest value column name in "draws" i coul use that value to pull value from table "coefficients".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use GREATEST() function
try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebfcfe/12/0)